# %%bash flush buffer

Tags: python, buffer, google-colaboratory

I created a simple test.py file:

```
import time
print("test")
time.sleep(5)
```

In google colab I execute this file on GPU:

```
%%bash
python -u test.py
```

`-u` should have forced unbuffering but if didn't. It still printed only after waiting for 5 seconds. How can I force the unbuffering while the file is being executed? In my real code there are various messages that are being printed during execution, I want to see them during evaluation and not wait till the end.

if I instead execute:

```
!python -u test.py
```

then it behaves as it should.

Comment: it works for me in colab; it prints and then sleeps.

Comment: You run on GPU?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to matter for me.

Comment: I don't understand then why it doesn't work on my colab notebook.

Comment: my backend is python 3.6.9.

Comment: Still the same problem both for python 3.8.5 and 3.7

Comment: Same with 3.6.9